# Block scope variables in 'For' and 'For-of' loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, let

```
// Prints
// Meow!
// I'm a talking cat!
// Callbacks are fun!

function go() {
   const messages = ["Meow!", "I'm a talking cat!", "Callbacks are fun!"];
   let msg = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      msg.push(function () {
          print(messages[i]);
      });
   }
   for (let fct of msg ) {
      fct();
   }
}
go();

// Prints
// Callbacks are fun!
// Callbacks are fun!
// Callbacks are fun!

function go() {
   const messages = ["Meow!", "I'm a talking cat!", "Callbacks are fun!"];
   let msg = [];
   for (let message of messages) {
      msg.push(function () {
          print(message);
      });
   }
   for (let fct of msg ) {
      fct();
   }
}
go();
```

I learned that let makes variables block-scoped and solves the shortcoming of using var to declare variables. i.e let allows each iteration to capture a different value for the variable. This works with the traditional for loop as my first example above shows. However, I was surprised that if I use the for..of loop structure in ES6, the variable 'message' is not captured for each iteration in the function closure! Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure this code prints the third message three times? It works for me.

Comment: The latter works as expected for me too. Though `console.log()` might have been a better option for debugging than `print()` :)

Comment: I'm glad you guys are getting the expected result. But yes, I'm getting the string "Callbacks are fun!" printed 3 times. Hmm.. now I'm perplexed why I get a different result than you guys.
I should probably say that I'm on Ubuntu604, and installed the Spidermonkey JS shell with version JavaScript-C24.2.0. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my JS shell is very outdated. When moving to the latest SpiderMonkey 45, it works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue was with how you're using the .push() method.
Try the code below, it will console log your array correctly with either syntax.

In this context, var and let would both have the same result.
All the variables you declared will only have scope within the function they're declared in.

```
function go() {
 const messages = ["Meow!", "I'm a talking cat!", "Callbacks are fun!"];
 let msg = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    msg.push(messages[i]);
    };

 for (let fct of msg ) {
    console.log('for',fct);
 };
};
go();

function go2() {
 const messages = ["Meow!", "I'm a talking cat!", "Callbacks are fun!"];
 let msg = [];
 for (let message of messages) {
    msg.push(message);
 };
 for (let fct of msg ) {
    console.log('for-of', fct);
 };
};

go2();
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerard was for taking a stab at this, but what your are suggesting is fundamentally different than what I was asking, and that was that it appeared like the variable capture in a function closure for a let declared variable wasn't working. But it does work for the latest Spidermonkey JS.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with pushing functions to an array. Pushing the messages themselves instead of the functions printing them is not the same thing.